# How to hide authoring information on webform for Drupal 7

Tags: 7, webforms

I went to Administration > Structure > Content Types > Webform > Manage Display where I am supposed to find a check box to hide or display author information but there is nothing there. Any idea how I could hide this?

Thank you for your thoughts

Drupal 7
Webform 3

Comment: I've got the same problem and when unticking this option it doesn't change anything. The authoring info is still displayed (I cleared the cache)! Help please!
Thanks,

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The author/date display is controlled in the edit form for the Webform content type, at http://mysite.com/admin/structure/types/manage/webform.

The checkbox you're looking for is here:

[image]